# Problem showing a font with license restriction to pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts

I'm programming to convert a file to pdf on mac, file contains a Chinese text

using a font STFangsong which has license restriction and is not embeddable, I

tried many CMaps to encode it, but it seems the root cause is because pdf viewer(both

mac previewer and acrobat reader) does not recognize the font, as shown in the pdf

file properties, Actual Font Unknown and there is a pop message says can't find or

create the font.

The PDF 32000-1:2008 9.6.6.4 tells a guideline that when encoding truetype font,

the font program should be embedded, though no specific explanation, from my

understanding, embedding can guarantee the pdf is readable everywhere, but I do not

need this since the font is licensed, I just want it can be shown on my computer.

So my question here is does those pdf viewer has limitation on those CJK characters

when embedding is forbidden?

By the way, I used Microsoft word to write a text with the font and save word to

pdf, and it shows the font is embedded subset, does it mean Microsoft have bought the

license?

Comment: @JamesRisner Yes TTF, Word is fine, just generate PDF without embedding the font.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for reply, I think the font author has the copyright, of course I can technically embed the font, it's just a file on my computer. When I use Apple Quatz or MS Word to pdf, the result is the font is embeded into pdf, so I wonder how these big companies deal with legal issue.  I have the font in font book, I think it's installed with system.